# TSV --> CSV in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

In Ruby, what's the most efficient way to convert a file of tab-separated values into CSV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'fastercsv'

FasterCSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "w") do |csv|
  File.open("/path/to/file.tsv") do |f|
    f.each_line do |tsv|
      tsv.chomp!
      csv << tsv.split(/\t/)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be properly parsing the TSV as well? `"foo\tbar"\t"baz"`

Comment: @Bill FasterCSV replaced the previous CSV module in Ruby 1.9, so in 1.9, you would `require 'csv'` and then double check it all working. The OP didn't mention which version they were using though.

Comment: @deceze -- I've never heard of a TSV format that allows "escaped" embedded tabs -- just splitting on the tab should do it.

Comment: `"Foo,Bar","Baz"` is perfectly valid CSV, why shouldn't TSV allow tabs in data fields?

Comment: The data I'm working with in Ruby 1.8.7 doesn't have tabs within the fields so this works (much appreciated Bill).

Comment: @deceze: many tools that have historically worked with TSV (at least in my experience) are quite primitive, and so embedded tabs... well, if they happened, they'd break things.  Which is as we'd get here.  But because they'd break things, they tended (in many cases, anyway) not to exist.  :)  As is the case here, according to @mbm.  :)

Comment: _"Note that fields that contain tabs are not allowable in this encoding."_ 
See the (very) short specification of TSV: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/tab-separated-values

Comment: Is there anyway to instead of outputting a new file, just keep the csv file stored in a variable in memory?